# Classifying Boston Housing Data based on 50th percentile using python

Tags: statistics, python

I am trying to complete the following problem using python.

The Boston housing dataset comes prepackaged with scikit-learn. The dataset has
506 data points, 13 features, and 1 target (response) variable. You can find more information
about the dataset here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.
datasets.load_boston.html.

Create the two following data set:
Boston50: Let τ50 be the median (50th percentile) over all t (response) values. Create a
2-class classification problem such that one class corresponds to label y=1 if t≥τ50 and
the other class corresponds to label y=0 if t<τ50.